# One row form in Bootstrap 4 non responsive if zoom

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I have a form on my site and I want it to show in one row. If I zoom it become non responsive on md sm and xs. Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbMgJB) with my example. Thanks for any help.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form class="col-md-12" style="display: flex; align-items: center">
                <label class="d-inline" for="inlineFormInput" style="font: 22px italic">Transaction Summary</label> 
 <label style="font-size: 12px" class="ml-1 mr-1" for="inlineFormInput">Submitted time</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 mr-lg-5" id="inlineFormInput" (select)="onDateSelection($event)" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [displayMonths]="2" [dayTemplate]="t" outsideDays="hidden" (click)="d.toggle()"/>
                <input style="width: 200px" class="form-control mr-1" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker (click)="d.toggle()" [markDisabled]="isDisabled" #d="ngbDatepicker">

            <ng-template #customDay let-date let-currentMonth="currentMonth" let-selected="selected" let-disabled="disabled" let-focused="focused">
            <span class="custom-day" [class.weekend]="isWeekend(date)" [class.focused]="focused"
                    [class.bg-primary]="selected" [class.hidden]="date.month !== currentMonth" [class.text-muted]="disabled">
            </span>
            </ng-template>
                <label style="font-size: 12px" class="mr-1" for="inlineFormInput">Status</label>
                <input type="text" style="width: 200px" class="form-control mb-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormInput">
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
                    <label style="font-size: 12px" class="mr-1 mt-1" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Search</label>
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text bg-white"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" style="width: 125px" class="form-control border-left-0 mr-2" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Enter anything here!">
                    <button type="text" class="btn btn-primary mr-2 d-inline"><i class="fa fa-search mr-1"></i>Filter</button>
                    <button type="text" class="btn btn-dark d-inline"><i class="fa fa-file-export mr-1"></i>Export</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: you want it to stay on the same line on mobile view?

Comment: If you want to have all the elements on the same row irrespective of  device size, use `col-auto` for the last `input-group` div.

Comment: add flex-wrap class to form tag

Comment: @godfather yes. and on md

Comment: @mahan when I add col-auto, buttons anyway moved down, not staying in row as I want

Comment: add flex-wrap:unset; <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 col-md-5 col-lg-4" style="flex-wrap:unset">

Comment: Remove `col-md-5 col-lg-4` and `col-auto` too if you have used it. And then, add only `flex-nowrap`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqbxyQ